# Gradle throwing API warning while trying to integrate Sentry

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, sentry

I'm trying to integrate Sentry into my app for crash monitoring.  I have followed the Sentry docs step by step but now I'm getting the following warning:

```
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessManifestProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessManifest(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
Affected Modules: app
```

It is due to the changes that I've made to my gradle files.  I couldn't find anything on SO or the Sentry docs regarding warnings of this nature.  It points directly to `apply plugin` but even that is the most recent version according to their website:

build.gradle(Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.sentry.android.gradle'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ozbek.onur.memegenerator"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "6.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.16'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
}
```

build.gradle(Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.sentry:sentry-android-gradle-plugin:1.7.16'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: it's not an error it's a warning :)

Comment: Okay.  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: I believe your library's gradle file is using 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' and it's been replaced. Can you search this in your whole project by pressing cntrl + shift + F ?

Comment: Just did.  No results.

Comment: Then this is being used in the library use just imported. And I am afraid you can't do much about it. Until it is updated

Comment: I figured.  Thanks.

Comment: Since the library is open source, you *could* submit a PR to fix this warning: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue on GitHub regarding this warning:

And [here's a comment](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/618#issuecomment-434461037) to why it wasn't dropped yet:

> OK so it looks like the new API was only added in Gradle 4.8
>
> I need our Plugin to work for people on 4.4 still, so I think we'll have to ignore this warning for now as people are slowly forced to use a newer Gradle by Play Store requirements.

There's also a [second issue where someone posted a fix on his fork.](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/661#issuecomment-490417169) As it was pointed out there, it requires now newer version of Gradle which means it'll break people using the older ones.

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  I guess I'll just ignore the error until they decide to do something about it.  So far it doesn't crash my app and that's what I care about.  I've upvoted and accepted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: There's a new comment where the author of the fork mentions doing the fix in a backward compatible way and offering a PR back to the Java SDK. This way the warning will be fixed permanently.